# Finding a string in a source code of a webpage

Tags: javascript

I am sorry in advance, I have almost no experience with programming so this is going to be a very basic, almost absurd, question, but the answer would save me a lot of time as I wouldn't have to do a very routine work. I would appreciate so much somebody's help!

**I would like to know how to find in a source code of a webpage a certain string.**

I am using a javascript code I found on the internet to help me with my studies of Portuguese. When I am learning a new word, I use the script to open multiple webpages (dictionary, webpage with pronunciation, etc.). Simplified version looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body style="background-color:grey">
    <p>What Portuguese word would you like to multisearch? Type below, then press enter please.</p>
    <input type="text" id="boxu" autofocus>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("boxu").onkeydown = function(e) {
        searchy(e)
      };

      function searchy(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          var q = document.getElementById("boxu").value;
          window.open("https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/portuguese-english/" + q);
          window.open("http://www.linguee.com/portuguese-english/translation/" + q + ".html");
          document.getElementById("boxu").value = "";
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

What I am trying to do: I would like to open in another tab (or directly download) audio file with the pronunciation of a given word. collinsdictionary.com have the pronunciation recorded on their website. Let's say I am doing a search for Portuguese word "cotovelo" (elbow). If I search in the source code of https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/portuguese-english/cotovelo for "https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/p/pt_/pt_br/pt_br_w", right after this string follows 7 digits I am looking for. In this case "0028290". The link for the audio file is "https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/p/pt_/pt_br/pt_br_w0028290.mp3".

The process is the same for every word I am looking for, I would like to write a script which automatizes this task of opening the source code, searching for the string of 7 digits, and opening the link in a new window. I was trying to search for the answer online and to write the code myself, but it's difficult without almost any programming knowledge.

Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: The ideal way would be to apply for an API key for collins dictionary, and then you can request the audio file directly from their service: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/api/

Answer (score 0):

I've written a short script for you to start with. It contains an input text where you enter the word page (URL) and when you click the 'Get pronunciation' button it generates a download link for the English sound of the word. The essence of the script is:

```
// makes a HTTP get request to the word's web page
$.get(url)
  .done(function(data) {
  // if request successful
  // wrap data to a new jQuery object
  var html = $(data);
  // look for your portugese sound link in this object 
  var mp3link = $(".audio_play_button.icon-volume-up.ptr", html);
  // now if found, do something with it - open in new tab or make download link
```

You can find the full content of the **working script** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vy4k5add/). I've tried to explain what the code does in the comments, so that if you want to improve/extend it, you know where to begin.

For example, if you enter the link `https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/portuguese-english/couracado` it will download the English pronunciation for the word *battleship*. Enjoy!